# Split sentence into quoted phrases if there is multiple AND, OR, NOT

Tags: javascript

I have following sentence:
Test OR OR Test

I need to detect first OR and don't include it in quotes. Output should be like this:

"Test" OR "OR Test"

It may be multiple OR|NOT|AND, output should be the same. Right now I can only detect only OR so output is "Test" OR OR "Test" but I need it to be "Test" OR "OR Test"

```js
const testItem = item => {
  if (item.match(/\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b/g) !== null) {
    return item.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/gi, (word) => {
      if (['AND', 'OR', 'NOT'].indexOf(word) < 0) return `"${word}"`;
      return word;
    });
  }
}
   console.log(testItem("Test OR OR OR OR OR Test"))
```

output should be "Test" OR "OR OR OR OR Test"

Comment: What should `Test OR OR OR Test` return?

Comment: "Test" OR "OR OR Test"

Comment: Why are you also removing one "Test" in your example ? Do you want to remove everything before that "OR" ?

Comment: And what about Test OR Test ?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please indicate the input and expected output

Comment: "Test" OR "Test"

Comment: Test OR OR OR OR Test => "Test OR "OR OR OR Test" and as much OR that will be after first one will be in quotes

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure snippet working correctly, I have errors

Comment: So fix it. Show your working code. The snippet I made was not intended to answer your question but to help us answer it using your code

Comment: I fixed and wrote expected output, what else should I do??

Comment: @rick1 One last question, is the first AND/OR/NOT always surrounded by exactly one space? Or can it be more? Or can it by any non-word character?

Comment: @Ivar it can be one or more spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(.*?)(\s+(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s+)(.*)
```

- `(.*?)` - Match anything as few as possible and put it in the first capturing group
- `(\s+(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s+)` - Match AND/OR/NOT surrounded by one or more whitespace characters and put it in the second capturing group
- `(.*)` - Match the rest of the string and put it in the third capturing group.

Now you can replace the string with the three capturing groups and surround the first and last groups:

```js
const testItem = item => item.replace(/(.*?)(\s+(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s+)(.*)/, '"$1"$2"$3"');

console.log(testItem("Test OR OR Test"));
console.log(testItem("Test AND OR Test"));
console.log(testItem("Test OR OR OR OR OR Test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's more to split, then here's a function that splits and reduces to the quoted phrases .

```js
 const quotePhrases = (str) => {
     let result = str
          .split(/(\s+(?:(?:OR|AND|NOT)\s+)+)/i)
          .reduce((acc, x) => {          
                 return acc += x.replace(/^(\s+(?:OR|AND|NOT)\s+)?(.*)$/, '$1\"$2\"');
               }, "");
            return result.replace(/"{2,}/g,'');;
      }
 
  console.log(quotePhrases('Test1 OR OR Test2 AND AND AND Test3'));
```